# Organizar as barras de um gráfico de barras no R

Tags: r

Estou plotando os seguintes dados no R para gerar um gráfico de barras:

```
structure(c(5483L, 28034L, 7995L, 5199L, 6785L, 7452L, 7692L), .Dim = 7L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("dom", "qua", "qui", "sáb", "seg", "sex", "ter")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

Estou gerando o seguinte gráfico:

```
coresBasicas <- c(1:7)
DataDeAcessoPlot<- barplot(table(DataDeAcesso[,4]),
                           main = "Exibições de Páginas por Dias da Semana",
                           ylim = c(0,30000),
                           xlab="Dias da Semana",
                           col = coresBasicas,
                           ylab="Exibições de Páginas",
                           cex.axis = 0.6,
                           #cex.names = 0.6,
                           las=1
)
text(x=DataDeAcessoPlot, y=table(DataDeAcesso[,4]), label=table(DataDeAcesso[,4]), pos = 3, xpd=NA)
```

Queria saber como organizar as colunas do gráfico na seguinte ordem: dom, seg, ter, qua, qui, sex, sáb. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primeira coisa a fazer é obter um vetor de dias da semana abreviados. Para isso vou usar as funções `Sys.Dat` e `weekdays`. Depois ordeno e aplico a função inversa (outra vez `order`).

```
# Hoje é segunda-feira, para começar no domingo tem que ser -1:5
y <- weekdays(Sys.Date() + -1:5, abbreviate = TRUE)
DDA <- DataDeAcesso[order(order(y))]
```

E é só adaptar o gráfico para usar este vetor `DDA`.

```
coresBasicas <- 1:7
DataDeAcessoPlot <- barplot(DDA,
                           main = "Exibições de Páginas por Dias da Semana",
                           ylim = c(0,30000),
                           xlab = "Dias da Semana",
                           col = coresBasicas,
                           ylab = "Exibições de Páginas",
                           cex.axis = 0.6,
                           #cex.names = 0.6,
                           las=1
)
text(x = DataDeAcessoPlot[, 1], y = DDA, label = DDA, pos = 3, xpd = NA)
```

**Edição importante.**
No código acima uso a função `Sys.Date` para obter uma segunda-feira. Ora isso muda a cada dia que passa e o resto deixa de funcionar. Não se deve obrigar o usuário a mudar a data do sistema só para dar certo com a data em que a pergunta foi feita e respondida, a data em que este código foi desenvolvido. Portanto a melhor solução é encontrar um dia fixo, que, já agora, seja por exemplo um domingo para servir de base ao vetor de datas de domingo a sábado, tal como é pedido na pergunta. Para isso basta alterar uma linha do código acima.

```
y <- weekdays(as.Date("2017-11-05") + 0:6, abbreviate = TRUE)
```

Obtemos o vetor

```
y
#[1] "dom" "seg" "ter" "qua" "qui" "sex" "sáb"
```

E o resto do código é exatamente igual e funciona sempre, hoje, amanhã, para o ano, etc.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo...Após executar o código para atribuir a variável y os dias da semana organizados, o próximo comando para atribuir ao DDA da erro, com a seguinte mensagem: `Error in `[.data.frame`(DataDeAcesso, order(order(y))) : 
  undefined columns selected` Já tentei especificar a coluna que corresponde aos dias da semana (coluna 4) mas mesmo assim não dá...

Comment: tenta `DDA <- DataDeAcesso[order(order(y)),]`

Comment: Não funcionou...Quando executei o comando `DDA <- DataDeAcesso[order(order(y)),]` o data frame DDA fica com apenas 7 linhas. Pelo que entendi, eu usaria a variável y para ordenar os dias da semana, que estão em `DataDeAcesso[,4]` se eu não especificar a coluna 4 em algum momento, como que as linhas serão organizadas?

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa É melhor editar a pergunta e postar a saída de `dput(DataDeAcesso)`. Assim podemos ver como está estruturada essa variável.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Agora compreendi e deu certo! Eu peguei o `dput(table(DataDeAcesso[,4])` e armazenei em uma nova variável `DiasDaSemanaEmFormatoValue`, essa nova variável não fica no formato de Data Frame daí o comando `DDA <- DiasDaSemanaEmFormatoValue[order(order(y)),]` deu certinho! Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @FábioJunioAlvesSousa Ainda bem que deu certo. Nota: quando li o seu código achei um bocado estranho tantas chamadas a `table`. Tem a certeza que são (todas) necessárias?

Comment: Sim pois com essa função que obtenho a frequência dos dados. Tenho uma base de dados com 60000 linhas, um dos atributos é este de data, o qual converti ele para o formato AAAA-MM-DD para depois obter o dia da semana para cada dia, então para mim saber a frequência dos dias da semana em 60000 linhas, eu uso a função `table()`.